# jQuery Selection

Tags: jquery

```
<div class="menu">
<ul>
<li><a href="#" target="_self" >Acme Inc.</a>
    <ul>
    <li><a href="#" target="_self">Christa Woods</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" target="_self">Charlotte Freeman</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" target="_self">Jeffrey Walton </a></li>
    <li><a href="#" target="_self">Ella Hubbard</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" target="_self">Sean Fletcher</a></li>
    </ul>
</li>
<li><a href="#" target="_self" >Widget Corp.</a>
    <ul>
    <li><a href="#" target="_self">Dylan Mack</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" target="_self">Roseanne Goodman</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" target="_self">Pedro Rivera</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" target="_self">Marion Cole</a></li>
    </ul>
</li>
<li><a href="#" target="_self" >Vendor LLC</a>
    <ul>
    <li><a href="#" target="_self">Hannah Moon</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" target="_self">Eduardo Vasquez</a></li>
    </ul>
</li>
</ul>
</div>
```

How do I select just the "Acme Inc", "Widget Corp" and "Vendor LLC" links - without selecting the sub li links. Basically I want to stop the header links from doing their default action.

Comment: are you able to make modifications to the markup?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use the [immediate child selector](http://api.jquery.com/child-selector/):

```
$('.menu > ul > li > a')
```

Alternatively, as pointed out by @regilero, the [`.children()` method](http://api.jquery.com/children/) does the same thing, and even is a bit more clear about what it does.

Comment: he wants the links...  add `> a` and +1foryou!

Comment: in complement: You could also use the children() function, has the difference between children() and find() is that children search in only one level jQuery("ul",jQuery(".menu")).children("li");

Answer (score 2):

You should set a class property on the links and select them in that way

```
<a class="hlink"></a>

$('.hlink').click(function(){
 modify click action here
});
```

Comment: This is indeed the only way to go in CSS because the child selector isn't supported in IE6. In jQuery however, where selectors have no compatibility issues, I would use `a > b` instead

Answer (score 1):

```
$('.menu > ul > li > a').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
});
```